# performSegueWithIdentifier:sender not working on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I have a storyboard that has a ViewController `DefaultViewController` which is neither a `UITabBarController` nor a 'UINavigationController`. It decides whether the upcoming controller should be a registration screen or home screen.

I have two segues originating from it, one pointing to `UINavigationController' that does registration while other moves to 'UITabBarController` that is the default home screen.

The `DefaultViewController` calls does following in `ViewDidAppear:` method

```
NSString *theController = nil;
if ([AppState sharedAppState].currentUserState == Registered) {
    theController = @"HomeSegue";
} else {
    theController = @"RegSegue";
}

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:theController sender:self];
```

The segue is performed well on iOS Simulator 5.1.1 as well as 6.0. However, nothing happens when I run the code on iPhone with iOS 5.1.1 or iPhone with iOS 6.0. The view stays with `DefaultViewController`s view.

**EDIT**
I created whole new project and works fine there but when I copied old storyboard contents and classes, issue re-appears.. !!

** EDIT 2 **
I removed the RootViewController associated with UINavigationController and added a simple UIViewController with a label on it and it works fine. If I add my Custom RegistrationController as root controller, the segue is not performed.

P.S. My custom `RegistrationController` adds another controller as childViewController in it.

Comment: It was working fine the other Day !!

Comment: Surely you have put break points in so you can step over the code and see which line is not working? You may have miss-keyed in the segue name for example, so try re-creating the segue when you know which one is trying to fire.

Comment: The Logs run when in simulator but not on device . I created whole new project and works fine there but when I copied old storyboard contents and classes, issue re-appears.. !!

Comment: Breakpoints should work on both simulator and device.

Comment: that is the problem. the `performSegueWithIdentifier` is called on both device & simulator however, the `prepareForSegue` method is not called when running on iOS Device while it called on iOS Simulator :(

Comment: made an edit see above .. !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange .. Very Very Strage.. But that is how I got it to work.

The `RegistrationController` that was part of navigationController, created an instance of `RegInfoController` which was added as both as it's subview as well as child controller.

I simply overrid the `awakeFromNib` method of that childController and it started working.

To Confirm the scenario, I removed the method and it stopped working..